# Does Hunter x Hunter manga progress further than the Anime?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I've just finished HxH anime and I still want to know what happened with Krollo and his gang and many other things.

[image: Killua smiling to Gon]

Answer (score 2):

The manga has released new chapters since the conclusion of the [***Hunter x Hunter***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter#Manga) 2011 anime. The anime ending corresponds with chapter 338 titled "Atop a Tree", currently there are a total of 380 chapters. I will note that if you are not familiar with ***[Yoshihiro Togashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro_Togashi)*** he takes frequent hiatuses from his work on the Hunter x Hunter manga so it is hard to expect a consistent release schedule. You can see all of the hiatuses here: ***[Hiatus x Hiatus](https://hiatus-hiatus.github.io/)***. If you would like some more information on the list of chapters that can be found here: [***List of Hunter x Hunter Chapters***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_chapters).

Comment: Is there a lot of filler in the new chapters?

Comment: There is no filler in a manga, filler is only used in anime. Manga is the source material so it is 100% cannon material.